# Use filtered Audio to drive an Animation

Tags: animation, import, audio

I want to create music visualization. To Do that I have learned to use Audio to create a curve and to drive Animations by it.
And i know, that I can Import Audio to the video editor, where i can filter audio.
Is there a direct way to combine both? That I can hipass or lopass audio to get bass only and to drive an animation by that?

Comment: No, the _Sequencer_ is considered post processing. Whatever you do in the sequencer is not affecting the scene before rendering. You can only import the audio in the sequencer, add the filters to it and then export the filtered audio from the main menu _Render_ > _Render Audio_ to have a new track to drive the curve by. But of course you could easily do this in some audio editing software and would not need Blender to get a bass track.